# How can i integrate existing fb album comments on a webpage in fb comment social plugin?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm wondering if it is possible to integrate existing facebook comments (from one of my facebook albums), to my website in the facebook comment social plugin (for that certain album), having all the necessary access permissions and knowing facebook album id.

I mean, I don't know what the href of fb:comments should be?!

```
  <fb:comments href="what should this one be?"  migrated="1"></fb:comments>
```

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to merge the arrays via the comments plugins, you can however request both arrays via graph api and merge them say using php or javascript then order them by date to give a natural flow.

refer to:  plugin comments http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/

refer to:  album comments http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/album/ #connections

refer to: array merge http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php